# Summarize information by group in data table in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get multiple summary statistics in R grouped by Team. I used code like below, but output is not what I want.

please point me in a better direction. Thanks!

```
set.seed(77)
data <- data.frame(Team =sample(c("A","B"),30, replace=TRUE),
                   gender=sample(c("female","male"),30, replace=TRUE),
                   Age =sample(c(0:100),30, replace=T))


dat <- data %>% 
  group_by(Team, gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarize_all(list(my_mean = mean,
                            my_sum = sum,
                            my_sd = sd)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

```
df <- data %>%
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarize(total = n(gender),
            mean = mean(Age),
            Max_Age = max(Age),
            Min_Age = min(Age),
            sd = sd(Age),
  )
```

I want to get like this pic.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74358477/10215301). Don't forget to upvote it, too..!

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera, Hi, I'm sorry about my reputation s not enough to vote. Thank you.

Comment: Now you can upvote if you want to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create the dataframe for the summary statistics of age per `Team` (`age_summary` in the example below) and that for the count of `Team` members per `gender` and `Team` (`gender_summary` in the example below), and then merge them into one dataframe (say `summary_df`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(77)
data <- data.frame(
  Team = sample(c("A", "B"), 30, replace = TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("female", "male"), 30, replace = TRUE),
  Age = sample(c(0:100), 30, replace = T)
)

age_summary <- data %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  summarize(
    mean = mean(Age),
    Max = max(Age),
    Min = min(Age),
    sd = sd(Age)
  ) %>%
  column_to_rownames("Team") %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble(
    rownames = "age_summary"
  )

gender_summary <- data %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  count(gender) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Team, values_from = n)

summary_df <- full_join(
  age_summary,
  gender_summary
) %>%
  mutate(
    "item" = if_else(
      is.na(gender),
      "Age",
      "Sex"
    )
  ) %>%
  unite("summary", c(age_summary, gender), na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
  relocate(item, .before = 1) %>%
  select(-c(age_summary, gender))

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   item  summary     A     B
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Age   mean     45.6  57.8
# 2 Age   Max      92    82
# 3 Age   Min       5    14
# 4 Age   sd       30.1  22.1
# 5 Sex   female    8     9
# 6 Sex   male      7     6
```